# Django - queryset and general SQL questions

Tags: python, django, query-optimization, django-queryset

**Firstly**, given a model `Foo` and it's m2m pointing to `Bar`, how does the following query work (when nothing really is `NULL` per se (join and first part ommited):

```
>> print Foo.objects.get(bar__isnull=True).query
...WHERE "barapp_bar"."id" IS NULL
```

The null stuff throws me off with regards to filtering by related m2m.

**Secondly**, is there a way to make this similar query faster when dealing with lots of rows:

```
Foo.objects.get(bar__in=[bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ommitted joins are important. If you look at the full query, you will see that Django does two [Left Outer Joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) from the `foo` table to the joining table `foo_bar` and to the `bar` table.

Consider two `foos` and two `bars`. Let `foo_1` be related to `bar_1` and `bar_2`, and `foo_2` not be related to any `bars`.

The query below with two left outer joins with include every `foo` at least once, and NULL will appear in the bar column for `foo_2` which is not related to any `bars`.

```
SELECT foo.id as foo_id, bar.id as bar_id 
FROM foo LEFT OUTER JOIN foo_bar 
  ON foo_id = foo_bar.foo_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN bar
  ON foo_bar.bar_id = bar.id;
+--------+--------+
| foo_id | bar_id | 
+--------+--------+
| 1      | 1      |
| 1      | 2      |
| 2      | NULL   |
+--------+--------+
```

The query for `Foo.objects.get(bar__isnull=True)` is similar to this, but it doesn't select anything from the bar table, and it filter on `bar.id` is `NULL`, because we only want the `foos` which are not related to any `bars`.

```
SELECT foo.id as foo_id 
FROM foo LEFT OUTER JOIN foo_bar 
  ON foo_id = foo_bar.foo_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN bar
  ON foo_bar.bar_id = bar.id
where bar_id is NULL;
+--------+
| foo_id | 
+--------+
| 2      |
+--------+
```

Comment: thanks! What about the second question, regarding an optimized query for achieving the same results? Is it even possible?

Comment: I don't have any suggestions for your second question. If you created the tables using Django's `syncdb` command, then your tables should have suitable indexes so that the query is efficient.